# AngularJS Alert is in DOM, should show but doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple test alert in my page. I can see the markup generated in the page DOM. It looks to me like it should show but it doesn't. Here is my code...

Controller

[image]

Html

[image]

Chrome console

[image]

Looking at the console output, should the alert be visible? It isn't. I'd sure appreciate an expert's advice.

Thanks for looking everyone :-)

**EDIT...**

Here is my main app.js file

[image]

Here is a better Controller clip

[image]

**EDIT 2...**

Here is computed style

[image]

Comment: You should change the `type="alert.type"` to `type="{{alert.type}}"`.

Comment: No, the directive works that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use UI Bootstrap, you need to create a closeAlert function (which probably throw an undefined error) in your controller like this :

```
$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Also don't forget to add the ui.bootstrap dependency in your app

Edit :

Make sure your element is not in display none :)

Comment: Thanks for helping Apercu! I added some extra screen caps to clarify your questions.

Comment: Could you give the computed CSS on the alert div ?

Comment: I just added a pic showing the computed style. I circled the display:none in red. Not sure why that's getting set?...

Comment: Can't say it without looking where this property is applied but that's your problem, you can easily target it in the console, or set a display block !important on it :)

Comment: I found in another css file where the alert was getting display none. Thanks for getting me to that. However, now it does show the alert, but it has no style at all. It doesn't even render the <b></b> html, it shows plain text. Stuff you can do with jQuery in 5 minutes, takes 5 hours to figure out in AngularJS. It's mind numbing :-/

Comment: Ok I got it rendering the background and border styles. That was my dumb mistake. I had type 'warn' instead of 'warning'. However it still isn't rendering the html in the message. I even tried <strong></strong> and you get the html tags in text. Any thoughts on why html isn't rendering? Thanks for all your advice. I'm almost fixed :-)

Comment: You could use `ng-bind-html` and add the `ngSanitize` as dependency.

Comment: But I recommand you to proceed another way, be cause angular is not really designed to rendre HTML content :)

Comment: I added the ng-bind-html to the alert markup in menu.html, then I had to wrap the alert message in the controller with $sce.trustAsHtml. The combination of these two finally got the alert to show the <b>/<strong> markup. Apercu, I really, really appreciate your help. I'm accepting your initial answer.

Comment: Apercu, what other way were you thinking I should do this?

Comment: You could just add a property "heading" in your alert object, and modify your view like `<strong>{{ alert.heading }}</strong>{{ alert.msg }}` that prevent to write HTML in the controller side.

Comment: Ugh, why didn't I think of that :-/ That is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code. I wanted to share. **Big thanks to Apercu** for getting me over the hump :-) The html goes in your view.html somewhere, maybe at top, and add the AlertService to your app and inject in the controller like normal...

**In your controller**

```
$scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
    AlertService.closeAlert(index);
};
```

**Alert html**

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
    <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></span>
</alert>
```

**AlertService**

```
angular.module('AJM.AlertService', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.service('AlertService', ['$rootScope', '$sce', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $sce, $timeout) {

    $rootScope.alerts = []; 

    var self = this;

    var addAlert = function (type, title, msg, seconds) {
        var index = $rootScope.alerts.length;
        $rootScope.alerts.push({ "type":type, "msg":$sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>' + title + '</strong> ' + msg) });
        if (seconds) {
            $timeout(function (index) {
                self.closeAlert(index);
            }, (seconds * 1000));
        }
        return true;
    };

    this.success = function (title, msg, seconds) {
        addAlert('success', title, msg, seconds);
    };

    this.info = function (title, msg, seconds) {
        addAlert('info', title, msg, seconds);
    };

    this.warning = function (title, msg, seconds) {
        addAlert('warning', title, msg, seconds);
    };

    this.danger = function (title, msg, seconds) {
        addAlert('danger', title, msg, seconds);
    };

    this.closeAlert = function (index) {
        $rootScope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

}]);
```